# Amazon EC2 - Fast AMI Creation in a Production Environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

We run a server architecture where we have an X number of base servers which are always on.  Our servers process jobs sent to them and the vast majority of our job requests come in during the workday.  To facilitate this particular spike in volume, we use EC2 auto-scaling.

I prefer to launch servers through auto-scaling with as much of a configured AMI as possible as opposed to launching from a base AMI and installing packages through long Chef or Puppet scripts.

In our current build process, we implement changes to our code base late at night when only our base servers are needed and no servers are launched through auto-scaling.  But every once in a while, we'll have a critical bug fix that needs to be implemented immediately during the day.

We have a rather large EBS hard drive associated with our servers (app. 400 GB) and AMI creation of a base server with the latest changes usually takes upwards of one hour.  This isn't a problem for late night deployments when no additional servers need to be launched, but causes us to lose valuable time during the day because it prevents us from launching additional servers when the latest AMI isn't ready.

Is there anything out there which can speed up the AMI creation process here?  I've heard of Netflix's [Aminator](https://github.com/Netflix/aminator) and [Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com/), but are there any other alternatives?  Also, how do these services stack up against one another?

Comment: Is that 400 GB the system volume or an additional volume to be created from an EBS snapshot and mounted? What technology stack is your application based on?

Comment: It's the system volume.  Stack is Windows 2012 R2 with IIS, PHP, and a core application written in C#